# exact match Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Can you please provide me VBA Code for Index Match function with "Exact Match", data to be extracted from different worksheet.

My code gives results for approximate match also.

Thanks
RK

```
Sub IndexMatch()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim MatchResult As Variant
    ' Set references to your worksheets
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    ' Find the last row in column B of Sheet1
    LastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    ' Loop through the rows in Sheet1
    For i = 4 To LastRow ' Assuming your data starts at row 2
        ' Use Index-Match to find the corresponding value in Sheet2
        On Error Resume Next
        MatchResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value, ws2.Range("G:G"), 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not IsError(MatchResult) Then
            ws1.Cells(i, 3).Value = ws2.Cells(MatchResult, "M").Value
        Else
            ' Paste "NA" in column C of Sheet1 when no match is found
            ws1.Cells(i, 3).Value = "NA"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

WorksheetFunction.Match() set the Err object, but not returns anything. In this case place the `On Error Goto 0` to the end of the If statement, because it resets Err.

Checking the Err need in the If statement in this case.

```
On Error Resume Next

    MatchResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value, ws2.Range("G:G"), 0)



    If Err=0 Then       'changed

        ws1.Cells(i, 3).Value = ws2.Cells(MatchResult, "M").Value

    Else

        ' Paste "NA" in column C of Sheet1 when no match is found

        ws1.Cells(i, 3).Value = "NA"

    End If
    On Error GoTo 0     'moved
```

or  (this returns the Error code) In this case no need of `On error`

```
'On Error Resume Next

    MatchResult = Application.Match(ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value, ws2.Range("G:G"), 0)  'modified

 '   On Error GoTo 0

    If Not IsError(MatchResult) Then

        ws1.Cells(i, 3).Value = ws2.Cells(MatchResult, "M").Value

    Else

        ' Paste "NA" in column C of Sheet1 when no match is found

        ws1.Cells(i, 3).Value = "NA"

    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

### A Case-Sensitive VBA Lookup

[image]

- Instead of using `Match` which matches case-insensitively, and to avoid a double loop, you could use the `Find` method with its `MatchCase` parameter set to `True`.

**Easy (Slow)**

```vb
Sub LookupExactMatchesFind()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim slrg As Range: ' lookup
    Set slrg = sws.Range("G2", sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp))
    Dim scOffset As Long: ' return
    scOffset = sws.Columns("M").Column - slrg.Column
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim dlrg As Range: ' lookup
    Set dlrg = dws.Range("B4", dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    Dim dcOffset As Long: ' return
    dcOffset = dws.Columns("C").Column - dlrg.Column
    
    Dim dCell As Range, sCell As Range, dVal As Variant
    
    ' Loop through the cells of the destination lookup column.
    For Each dCell In dlrg.Cells
        dVal = dCell.Value
        If Not IsError(dVal) Then
            If Len(dVal) > 0 Then
                Set sCell = slrg.Find(dVal, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , True)
            End If
        End If
        If sCell Is Nothing Then
            dCell.Offset(, dcOffset).Value = "NA"
        Else
            dCell.Offset(, dcOffset).Value = sCell.Offset(, scOffset).Value
            Set sCell = Nothing
        End If
    Next dCell
    
End Sub
```

**Hard (Fast)**

- By using arrays and a dictionary, it will become more efficient.

```vb
Sub LookupExactMatchesDict()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim rVal, r As Long
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim slData, srData
    With sws.Range("G2", sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp))
        slData = .Value
        srData = .EntireRow.Columns("M").Value
    End With
    
    ' Source to Dictionary
    Dim sDict As Object: Set sDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    'sDict.CompareMode = vbBinaryCompare ' default
    For r = 1 To UBound(slData, 1)
        rVal = slData(r, 1)
        If Not IsError(rVal) Then
            If Len(rVal) > 0 Then
                sDict(rVal) = srData(r, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim dData, drrg As Range
    With dws.Range("B4", dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
        dData = .Value
        Set drrg = .EntireRow.Columns("C")
    End With
    
    ' Loop
    Dim IsFound As Boolean
    For r = 1 To UBound(dData, 1)
        rVal = dData(r, 1)
        If Not IsError(rVal) Then
            If Len(rVal) > 0 Then
                If sDict.Exists(rVal) Then IsFound = True
            End If
        End If
        If IsFound Then
            IsFound = False
            dData(r, 1) = sDict(rVal)
        Else
            dData(r, 1) = "NA"
        End If
    Next r

    ' Write        
    drrg.Value = dData
    
End Sub
```